# Can't create DatabaseContext from service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services, asp.net-identity-2

I have a service.

```
scheduler.Start();

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ReportJob>()
           .WithIdentity("reportJob", "reportGroup")
           .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
           .WithIdentity("reportTrigger", "reportGroup")
           .StartNow()
           .WithCronSchedule("0 * * ? * Fri")
           .Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

In ReportJob I have

```
 var repository = new StoreReportRepository();
 repository.GenerateReports();
```

in GenerateReports I try to get access to DatabaseContext

```
var db = new DatabaseContext()
```

There I receive the error:

> Foreign key 'FK_dbo.UserSession_dbo.User_UserId' references invalid
>   table 'dbo.User'. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

Constructor DatabaseContext():

```
    public ObjectContext Context
    {
        get {

            return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        }
    }

    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("name=DatabaseContext")
    {
        this.Context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

What did I do wrong? 
Thanks

PS UserSession.cs

```
public class UserSession
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Look at your error - invalid table `dbo.User`. Check this table, does it actually exist.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have this table. And method GenerateReports works, but only if I run it from controller

Comment: @PeterSmith Is it possible that reason is asp.net identity?

Comment: is it possible for you to post the dbml table association ? if you dont authenticate user in your scheduling service , guess you dont need that associations

Comment: @AmitPore I can't sorry. I can tell you that I don't touch User table or UserSession table. In two words I use one table for calculate weekly payment

Comment: @Badfishmaan ok , but looks like those table exist in your dbml and association . if you don use it , i would suggest to remove tables or the association between the table you using (say payments ) and User

Comment: @AmitPore I can't remove table. And I can't delete association between tables. In any way I can't create a context. It breaks at this line: `var db = new DatabaseContext()`

Comment: Can I suggest you try pointing your connection string at a empty Db and let entity framework create the database structure for you, then test if you still get this error.. it could be that the existing database structure does not match what the DbContext is expecting?

Comment: @uk2k05 Hmm.. Looks like I can't create a new db. I get the same error

Comment: Is this a code first entity framework project?  or EF designer with .edmx file?

Comment: @uk2k05 It is a code first entity framework project

Comment: Does this post help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499969/c-sharp-foreign-key-references-invalid-table-basic-migration-not-working

Comment: @uk2k05 I updated question

Comment: @uk2k05 I tried to remove UserSession table. But I still get this error

Comment: @uk2k05 I am sure that windows service connects to wrong database. It creates new, because new db is empty. I have no idea why. I have the same connections strings as in web.config

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which works for me. 
The problem was in that windows service was run from wrong account. So it creates new db. I changed account and everything works.

In services find your service -> right click -> properties -> tab Log On -> enter your account name and pwd.[image: example]